# NewLine in "Description" Attribute?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

How can I include a *newLine* char in the `System.ComponentModel.Description` atribute?

```
  <System.ComponentModel.Description("Specifies the precision of decimal numbers\n(min 2 for Currency and Percent;  20 for Decimal)")> _
  Public Property Precision() As Integer
```

Comment: It seems to me that your question is specific to VB...

Comment: can u tell me why u want to do it? just curious

Comment: @Bumble Bee: because I have a long phrase first part is the property explanation, the second some precisions (between parenthesis)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Not at all. Do you have a solution for C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use basically the same code in C#, it will at least have the newline character in the attribute value:

```
[Description("Specifies the precision of decimal numbers\n etc"]
public int Precision { ... }
```

Now how Visual Studio *handles* that is a different matter. You may want to try `\r\n` instead of just `\n`.

I suspect the reason you're currently seeing `\n` in the designer at the moment is that VB doesn't escape strings in the same way. In VB you could *try* using `vbCrLf` (the equivalent of `\r\n`):

```
<Description("Specifies the precision of decimal numbers" & vbCrLf & "...")>
```

Comment: I tried Environment.NewLine, this didn't work because is not constant expression. but vbCrLf works like a charm.

Comment: @serhio: `vbCrLf` will *always* be "\r\n" whereas `Environment.NewLine` changes by platform, basically.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that *you already have*. The issue, perhaps, is getting whatever you are using (I'm guessing `PropertyGrid`?) to render the return. That is outside your control. You might also *try* using crlf, `\r\n`, but no guarantees there either.

Comment: yeah. in the Visual Studio property grid I want "bla bla" newLine "blaaa blaa" but I have "\n" instead...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had success with using \n or \r\n.  Instead, I have had to use the HTML tag of `</br>` to get a line-break.